# Is it possible to pass a dictionary of objects from a view to a template

Tags: python, django

I am wondering if we can pass a dictionary of objects to a template and loop it in a template.

This is my structure:

```
{
    'Communication': [
                        [EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object],
                        [EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object]
                        ],
    'escalations': [[EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object],
                    [EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object]]
}
```

It is basically a dictionary where for each key, the value is a list of list.

I would like to know if there is a way to loop on this within a django template or if this kind of structure is too complicated,

Comment: Yes you can, what part are you struggling with?

Comment: Hi Sayse, thank you for your answer, I tried different structures just like the one that Paul advised but it is not working; In Paul's example, value should contain an EchoCase Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it worked using Paul's structure

```
{% for category, liste in template_dictionnary.items %}
    <ul>
        <li> {{ category }} </li>
        <li> {{ liste}} </li>
            {% for val in liste %}
                <li>Val: {{ val.0.comment }}</li> <!-- val.0 is an EchoCase, val.1 is an EchoDescription -->
                <li>Val: {{ val.1.field }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you Paul

Comment: No problem, I misread your structure originally, but you might consider how your queryset puts the data together as a dictionary and then you can use a list of dictionary values with sublists.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for key, value_list in data %}
    <ul>
        <li> {{ key }}
            <ul>
            {% for value in value_list %}
                <li>{{ value }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

But it looks like Echo Case and Echo Description are related so you might just want to use related fields and do {{ echocase }}  {{ echocase.description }} or something similar

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your answer, when I am doing this, I just have the first letter of the key    <ul>
        <li> C
            <ul>
            
   
    <li> o  </li>
   
            
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li> e
            <ul>
            
   
    <li> s  </li>
   
            
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

Comment: Whoops, I would make it a list of dictionaries.

[{
    'Communication': [
                        [EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object],
                        [EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object]
                        ],
    'escalations': [[EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object],
                    [EchoCase: EchoCase object, EchoDescription: EchoDescription object]]
}]

Comment: When using your code: {u'Communication': [[<EchoCase: EchoCase object>, <EchoDescription: EchoDescription object>], [<EchoCase: EchoCase object>, <EchoDescription: EchoDescription object>]], u'escalations': []}
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py:208: RemovedInDjango110Warning: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1. This will raise an exception in Django 1.10.
  RemovedInDjango110Warning)